# Unable to launch Airflow Webserver in fresh install

Tags: python-3.x, webserver, airflow

I'm trying to launch `$ airflow websever` (on newly installed instance) but the web server does not start (the browser states: `This site can’t be reached`).

In the terminal I got following error message

> Running the Gunicorn Server with:
>
> Workers: 4 sync
>
> Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
>
> Timeout: 120 Logfiles:
>
> ## > Error: cannot import name 'models'

here are the steps I took, as per [Airflow Quick Start](https://airflow.apache.org/start.html) :

- just made an install of `pip install apache-airflow` in fresh virtualenv (py3.6)
- set the AIRFLOW_HOME env variable: `export AIRFLOW_HOME=$(pwd)`
- Initialize Airflow DB.. `airflow initdb`

using PyCharm, macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Thanks a lot for taking a look at it.

**UPDATE:** a simple statement `from airflow import models` is throwing an error *ImportError: cannot import name 'models'*. Howevre, when I try in Python Console, the module seems to import successfully

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED** my own python file was named airflow.py that was causing the name clash.. PY interpreter wa looking models module in my own airflow.py instead from airflow package's...

restrain from naming your own PY module / package as airflow.

hope it helps others